# Defining precision for numeric data type of Postgres DB in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using Postgres Database with **Entity Framework Core**.

In my database, Price table has column `price(numeric)` and values like **12345.123456789012345678901234567890** are stored i.e. (high precision)

When I fetch data using LINQ query, everytime I got the error :

> "System.OverflowException: Numeric value does not fit in a
>   System.Decimal"

I have found method of using `Property.HasColumnType("decimal(20,5)")` for column of database in `OnModelCreating()` method of DbContext but its not working. Also, I have seen defining select query in edmx file but **Entity Framework Core** does not generate edmx file.

So, how can we define precision for numeric data type of Postgres with **Entity Framework Core** in C#? (Note: Precision can be reduced to at least 5 decimal places)

Comment: what is your linq query

Comment: what is  Model Properties Price Datatype?

Comment: linq query : dBContext.PriceTable.Where(x => x.id == 2).First().Value;

Comment: Price data type is numeric

Comment: numeric is sql DataType ,What is Frontend dataType decimal ,int ,float, and double

Comment: Can you show your entity configuration (Fluent API or Data Annotations) ?

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<PriceTable>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.PkPrice)
                    .HasName("PK_Price");

                entity.ToTable("price_table");

                entity.Property(e => e.PkPrice)
                    .HasColumnName("pk_price")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();
     
    entity.Property(e => e.Dated)
                    .HasColumnName("dated");

                entity.Property(e => e.Value)
     .HasColumnName("value")
     .HasColumnType("decimal(25,5)");

            });

Comment: @KariKalan: Frontend dataType is decimal

Comment: you have stored decimal value  m used this used same format for float pi=3.14f

Answer (score 0):

[image]Decimal not support to high precision so you have Used Double
Other Wise Price Value Convert to Decimal Value

Example:

1.stored value 
price=1234.12345678901234567890

```
tabledetails.Select(c =>(decimal) c.value).ToList();
```

Get Vlaue is 1234.12345678901

2.Other wise The before stored the  Price Value using decimal then
using below format

store Value

1234.12345678901234567890m

Get Value

1234.12345678901234567890